# Is there a way to 'lock' the last item in a ListView to always show?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-3.5, listview

I am listing folders and folder sizes in a ListView for a VB.NET WinForm program I'm writing.  I would like to total the folder sizes in the last entry of the ListView and 'lock' it show it always shows (even if scrolling through the list.

Is there a way to do this?  I'd really like to avoid adding another control on the Windows Form to display the total.

**EDIT:**
Space is somewhat of an issue as I'm trying to keep this window small enough to work in a min screen resolution of 800x600 (I know, waaaaay not the standard, but I want to make this available to even those in the elderly community with problematic eyesight.

Thanks!

-JFV

Comment: Can you expand on *why* you do not wish to add another control? Presumably space is not an issue as you are proposing using the bottom line of the ListView to show the totals permanently.

Comment: Whether you put it in the grid or add a control, isn't it still going to take up space?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: If I keep in in the ListView, then it is still in the fixed space used by the ListView.  If I can lock the last entry from not scrolling, but let the rest of the list scroll, then I can have my cake and eat it too!

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be ways to do this in Webforms and WPF, but not in Winforms.  You should probably use a text box.  Any attempt to hack in a fixed totals row would most certainly be far more effort than the benefit obtained.  It is certainly beyond my capabilities.  Even the custom control shops like Telerik don't seem to do this.

```
http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx
```

If you're concerned about space, make the gridview a little smaller to accomodate the text box.